# Carousel slider with data retrieved from firebase realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

What I would like is to retrieve the data from a Firebase Realtime Database query instead of the List I created manually.
Here I am using a flutter package which is CarouselSlider and I am retrieving the data from a list written manually by myself while what I would like is to retrieve the content of my slider from a query.
Thanks for your help.

Here is my complete code:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flyzik/size_config.dart';

class SliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SliderWidget> createState() => _SliderWidgetState();
}

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zfly2020-151d6.appspot.com/o/images_slide%2F3b1ab9f0-671a-11eb-bbaf-6ef0e5b93f8c.jpeg?alt=media&token=2b10908d-edb5-4527-9130-a5e076972e88',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zfly2020-151d6.appspot.com/o/images_slide%2FCopie%20de%20Red%20and%20black%20Black%20Friday%20sale%20Twitter%20post%20-%20Fait%20avec%20PosterMyWall.jpg?alt=media&token=2c39e317-859c-4560-963a-8374fe34fbcc',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zfly2020-151d6.appspot.com/o/images_slide%2F6169541506df6_61695418e5c29.jpg?alt=media&token=4c250834-d4f9-4946-93d6-c4bba58766c4',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zfly2020-151d6.appspot.com/o/images_slide%2F20211211_234252.jpg?alt=media&token=1cb1edcc-bf80-4fbd-a419-2c175e85997f',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zfly2020-151d6.appspot.com/o/images_slide%2Frap%20(1).jpg?alt=media&token=a2f3996f-b2d9-4cfd-81d2-1fe5c0becb6a'
];

class _SliderWidgetState extends State<SliderWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: true,
          aspectRatio: 2.0,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
        ),
        items: imageSliders,
      ),
    );
  }

  final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
      .map((item) => Container(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
          child: Center(
            child: Image.network(
              item,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 1500.0,
              height: getProportionateScreenHeight(300),
            ),
          )),
    ),
  ))
      .toList();
}
```

thank

This the result of all modification
[First part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFuoV.png)

[Second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r3NO.png)

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLd49.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch content with a method and use `FutureBuilder` to fetch it for you automatically.

```dart
  Future<DataSnapshot> fetchList() async {
    const path = 'SET YOUR PATH HERE';
    return await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(path).get();
  }
```

Wrap your `Widget` with `FutureBuilder`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
        future: fetchList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            final imgList = List<String>.from(snapshot.data?.value as List);

   return Container(
      child: CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(
          autoPlay: true,
          aspectRatio: 2.0,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
        ),
        items: imageSliders(imgList),
      ),
    );
  }
);
return Text('Error');
}

  final List<Widget> imageSliders(List<String> imgList) => imgList
      .map((item) => Container(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
          child: Center(
            child: Image.network(
              item,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 1500.0,
              height: getProportionateScreenHeight(300),
            ),
          )),
    ),
  ))
      .toList();
}
```

Use `imgList` to map your data into `Widget`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I didn't understand how to implement all this code. Please put the whole code with your modification.

Comment: I have an error with the method imageSliders(imgList), no way to make a map item

Comment: What's the error

Comment: ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DataSnapshot>#ca305):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot> FutureBuilder:file:///Users/user/Documents/FLUTTER/MYAPP/APP/lib/widgets/slider_widget.dart:20:12

Comment: Do you have any data in Realtime Database?

Comment: Yes, i'have the data in realtime

Comment: Did you set the path here? `const path = 'SET YOUR PATH HERE';`

Comment: yes put path='slide'.

Comment: Ok. Can you please send a screenshot of structure of your database from realtime database. The error must not be `null` if the path is right.

Comment: It's done, you can see the screenshot I added to my post

Comment: Ok. It has nested objects and not similar to the example you provided of `imgList`.

Comment: Please provide print output of these informations. `snapshot.data`, `snapshot.data.value`, `snapshot.data.value.runtimeType`

Comment: it's not possible to use snapshot.data or snapshot.data.value, snapshot.data.value.runtimeType

Comment: You can put it under `builder: (context, snapshot) {`

Comment: Sorry, my keyboard misspelled snapshot, let me send you back the print results